# Delphi download files in a directory

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I have found some solutions but they are too much sophisticated or simply they don't work. I have to download 200 pictures from a server (small pictures, about 15 kB for each one). I thought that I could use IdHTTP:

```
procedure TForm2.DownloadFile(filename, path: string);
var Stream: TMemoryStream;
    Url: String;
begin

  Url := filename;
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(Url, Stream);
    Stream.SaveToFile(path);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;

end;
```

This is the most common way I guess and it works pretty fine. By the way, according with what I have said above, I have to download more than a file and the solution would be:

```
DownloadFile('www.website.com/folder/file1.png', 'C:\folder\file1.png');
DownloadFile('www.website.com/folder/file2.png', 'C:\folder\file2.png');
DownloadFile('www.website.com/folder/file3.png', 'C:\folder\file3.png');
```

And so on. I also have a **progressbar** that indicates the progression of the downloads.

**Question**

Is there a more efficient way to do this? 
Like for instance passing to IdHTTP a list containing all the links and the file names that have to be downloaded.

Comment: Why do you use a memory stream if you want the content in a file? Use a file stream. If you have multiple files, use a loop.

Comment: Using a loop for the file stream?

Comment: No. Loop over the list of files downloading each one. Instead of making distinct calls to DownloadFile.

Comment: Ok so I should make DownloadFile(); [no parameters] and then make a loop with the try - finally? Is that what you mean? Thanks

Comment: No. Just run a loop over the file names and call DownloadFile in the body of the loop.

Comment: Ah ok I got it thanks. Just the last question: the event that manipulates the progressbar I have create will work anyway, wont it?

Comment: Progress is a little more tricky. Ideally you'd want to know the total size to be downloaded, and then keep track of how much you'd downloaded.

Comment: create a procedure `DownloadFiles` and use 2 parameters:  `URLS: TStrings` and `SavePath: string`. now loop the `TStrings` (You pass `TStringList` for example), call `DownloadFile(URLS[i]...)` and update the progress bar in each iteration. P.S: in general `IdHTTP` is blocking so you will experience a non responsive UI if you use this in the main UI thread - better do each download in a single thread. plenty of example out there...

Comment: Yeah that is was what I was gonna do @kobik ;) To prevent the "block" I was thinking to put Enabled := False to the button and show a Label like "Downloading please wait..."

Comment: Personally I'd prefer to see an array which I would regard as more flexible

Answer (score 4):

You can use Generics like TDictionary :

```
function DownloadFiles(FilesInfo: TDictionary<string, string>): Boolean;
var
  FileNo: Integer;
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  for FileNo := Low to High do
  begin
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(FilesInfo.Values[FileNo], fmCreate);
    try
      IdHTTP1.Get(FilesInfo.Keys[FileNo], Stream);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Use :

```
var
  FilesInfo: TDictionary<string, string>;
begin
  FilesInfo := TDictionary<string, string>.Create();
  try
    FilesInfo.Add('www.website.com/folder/file1.png', 'C:\folder\file1.png');
    FilesInfo.Add('www.website.com/folder/file2.png', 'C:\folder\file2.png');
    FilesInfo.Add('www.website.com/folder/file3.png', 'C:\folder\file3.png');
    DownloadFiles(FilesInfo);
  finally
    FilesInfo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: A dictionary seems like a poor choice. An array would make sense. Your for loop syntax is badly broken.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please explain why dictionary is poor choice .

Comment: Because an array is more efficient and simpler